# Putting output from Matcher into array then comparing values in array

Tags: java, arrays, matcher

I have the following code where I want to catch the values of doub and put them into an array. As a beginner I'm trying to get all the outputs of the variable doub and put them into the array using the line...

```
double[] x = new double[(int) doub];
```

and although this code compiles I just get values like [D@116ab4e when I print x out.  I guess this is because I am casting the double as an int but its double. However if I dont do this the code doesn't compile. Im just plain stuck! so any suggestions would be appreciated thanks!

```
                    String[] shadingarray = str.split(";");

                    for (String str1: shadingarray){
                        Matcher search = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(str1); 
                        while (search.find()){ 
                            double doub = Double.parseDouble(search.group(1)); 

                            double[] x = new double[(int) doub];
```

I should also add the type of doubles that doub equals, they are like the following:

```
3.0
6.4855612
4.0
0.6161728763
4.0
2.2012378517
4.0
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you show some sample input and what doubles you want to parse from it?

Comment: You didn't state the problem you're facing. Does it compile? What is the output? and and and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to rework your loop:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>()
while ( search.find() ) { 
    list.add( Double.parseDouble(search.group(1)) )
}
```

if you want it as an array, then

```
double x[] = list.toArray();
```

Also if you `System.out.println( x )` you're going to get something like `[D@116ab4e`, which  essentially means "array of double" (`[D`) followed by the hashcode of your array object. You'll probably want to

```
for ( i=0; i<x.length; i++ ) { System.out.println( x[ i ] ); }
```

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer I actually worked that out even so my code is still weird because I am only getting zeros prints out when I print out the array. What would be the right code so that the array would contain the real values of the doubles... e.g 2.2012378517 etc

Comment: Well for one thing don't cast them to `int` :-)

Comment: Ok but the issue is if I have this code double[] x = new double[doub];  It wont compile and eclipse asks me to cast it as an int it; only lets me complile if it is cast as an int

Comment: See amended answer above, you're creating a new array of size `doub` which of course only makes sense for integer values.

Comment: Ok thanks very helpful but I'm getting an error underlining List<Double> which says - the type list is not generic it cannot be paramertized with arguments what does this mean?

Comment: That means you're using an ancient JDK. Generics were introduced in Java 5. If you're on JDK5 or later, your source- and/or target-level might be set to 1.4 or less. Look in the Eclipse project properties popup for those.